# JUnit тестирование. Рабочая директория

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit

Пишу юнит тесты для своей программы. В тестах мне нужно передать имена файлов и пару строк. Вот пример:

```java
@org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
void AllArgumentsRight() {
    String[] args = {"repeatSomeStringsInput.txt", "repeatSomeStringsOutput.txt", "test", "f"};
    Replace.checkArguments(args);
}
```

В чем проблема: JUnit не видит файлы. Почему? Потому что в разделе Edit Configurations мы увидим рабочую директорию: $MODULE_WORKING_DIR$. Я в ручную проставлял ту папку, в которой у меня лежат эти файлы. Мне это надоело. Что сделать, что бы внутри этого проекта у меня рабочая директория для JUnit была та, которая мне нужна. Я, конечно, допускаю, что сам подход к тестированию у меня не правильный. Буду рад если растолкуете все по полочкам. Пишу в Intellij IDEA

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете сборщик проектов(да и если не используете), то, скорее всего, у вас структура проекта выглядит как-то так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Файлы из папок resources попадают в classpath, к ним можно легко получить доступ через класс `ClassPathResource`

Самый простой и более или менее правильный способ для загрузки тестовых файлов(допустим, текстовых) - держать файлы в тестовых ресурсах, и загружать их в память в отдельном методе. 
Код будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
private String testResource;

@Before
void uploadTestResource() {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    try(InputStream inputStream = new ClassPathResource("testResource.txt") {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line;
    while((line = reader.readLine) != null) {
        builder.append(line).append("\n");
    }
    testResource = builder.toString();
    catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте передавать путь к ресурсам так:

```
ИмяВашегоТестКласса.class.getResource("путь_к_файлу_ресурсов_и_его_имя_относительно_папки_resource").toString()
```